# body not containing content / in conjunction with weighted footer

Tags: html, css

Please see jsFiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/y7fPK/1/

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
}

.page-wrapper {
min-height: 100%;
height: auto !important;
height: 100%;
}
```

and a buffer and footer...  fiddle will make more sense.

sticky footer working well but body is not extending to contain content when scrolling down.

[image]
VS. (when scrolling down)
[image]
see this orange ?  the red is the body and the HTML is the orange... It isn't reaching past the view-port.
If I remove height: 100% from body, this solves that - but then the footer jumps up to the end of the content.
It seems like the 100% height is just of the view-port.  which makes sense... but I want the body to be as big as the HTML... Any Ideas ???

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Your fiddle works fine. Can you post an example where the situation you describe is occurring?

Comment: if you make the fiddle view-port smaller then the content area / and you scroll down... you will see a pink background showing that the body is not filling the html.  Thanks.

Comment: Actually if you use a tool like Chrome's Developer Tools, you'll see that the body element *does* fill the HTML. The problem is that the HTML element doesn't fit the page. (The pink background color gets set on the root document element, not the HTML in this case.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple overflow hidden on the wrapper seems to be doing the trick for me.

Here's a pen.

http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/DiewF

**HTML:**

```
<html><body>

    <div class="wrapper">

      <header>
          HEADER
      </header>

      <section class="main-content">
          MAIN CONTENT
      </section> <!-- end .main-content -->

      <div class="footer-buffer">BUFFER</div>

    </div><!-- end .wrapper -->

    <footer>
        FOOTER
    </footer>

</body></html>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important; /* for IE 6 */
  height: 100%; /* for IE 6 */
  margin: 0 auto -4em;

  /* new addition */
  overflow: hidden; /* this seems to do the trick */
  /* remove this to see the problem */
}

footer, .footer-buffer {
  height: 4em;
}
```